# JBOSS Cli adding connector,acceptor and Connection factory

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6, jboss-cli

i need to create connector,acceptor and connection factory for the hornet Q subsystem.Iam getting below error while connecting to it.Can you please tell me what could be wrong with my cli

hornetq.txt

```
batch
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-connector=netty-ssl:add(socket-binding=ssl-messaging)
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-connector=netty-ssl/param=ssl-enabled:add(value=true)
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-connector=netty-ssl/param=trust-store-path:add(value="/opt/jboss/security/CompanyServerTruststore.jks")
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-connector=netty-ssl/param=trust-store-password:add(value="changeit")
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-acceptor=netty-ssl:add(socket-binding=ssl-messaging)
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-acceptor=netty-ssl/param=ssl-enabled:add(value=true)
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-acceptor=netty-ssl/param=key-store-path:add(value="${jboss.web.ssl.keystore:/opt/jboss/security/CompanyServerKeyFile.jks}")
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-acceptor=netty-ssl/param=key-store-password:add(value="${VAULT::CompanyKeystore::keystore_pw::1}")
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/connection-factory=SSLRemoteConnectionFactory:add(connector={"netty-ssl"=>undefined}, entries = ["java:jboss/exported/jms/SSLRemoteConnectionFactory"])
run-batch
```

Error :

```
C:\Temp\FSW\jboss-eap-6.1\bin>jboss-cli.bat --connect --file=C:\Temp\hornetq.txt
#1 /subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-connector=netty-ssl:add(socket-binding=ssl-messaging)
#2 /subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-connector=netty-ssl/param=ssl-enabled:add(value=true)
#3 /subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-connector=netty-ssl/param=trust-store-path:add(value="/opt/jboss/security/CompanyServerTruststore.jks")
#4 /subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-connector=netty-ssl/param=trust-store-password:add(value="changeit")
#5 /subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-acceptor=netty-ssl:add(socket-binding=ssl-messaging)
#6 /subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-acceptor=netty-ssl/param=ssl-enabled:add(value=true)
#7 /subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-acceptor=netty-ssl/param=key-store-path:add(value="${jboss.web.ssl.keystore:/opt/jboss/security/CompanyServerKeyFile.jks}")
#8 /subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/remote-acceptor=netty-ssl/param=key-store-password:add(value="${VAULT::CompanyKeystore::keystore_pw::1}")
#9 /subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/connection-factory=SSLRemoteConnectionFactory:add(connector={"netty-ssl"=>undefined}, entries = ["java:jboss/exported/jms/SSLRemoteConnectionFactory"])
{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-9" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.SSLRemoteConnectionFactory" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.messaging.default.jms.c
onnection-factory.SSLRemoteConnectionFactory: JBAS011639: Failed to create connection-factory
    Caused by: HornetQException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=HQ129005: Connector {0} not found on the main configuration file]"}}}}
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection factory is not able to find connector added. Hence you need to remove connection-factory add operation out of batch process, reload server and then add CF. Added connector will bound to server after reload only.

Comment: Is this how cli scripting works with jboss,is there a way I can create all the connectors acceptors and connection factory in a single batch process execution..

Comment: Yes. we can not create connector and connection factory which is using it simultaneously.